# Receive an HTTP request and respond with a Java program

Tags: java, http, streaming, vlc

VLC player can play file streams by providing it the right URL.

My intention is to make a Java program that listens to a local address and port for an HTTP request from VLC, and then responds with a stream of a video file.

The question is how can I listen for HTTP requests on a specific address and port, and then how could i stream my video file as an http responce back to VLC.

I am aware that there are various libraries from Apache, but i need something simpler.

Comment: What's your question?  What have you tried?

Comment: Simpler than libraries that wrap the complexities of the raw APIs?

Comment: Sorry, my question is not clear. I will correctly edit my post.

Comment: @DaveNewton I just want to do some testing on that, and adding external libraries sounds too much. But if the alternative is not as easy as i think it will be, then of course you will be right.

Comment: @kit-kat - Adding external libraries is the cornerstone of what makes Java a great platform. Libraries are designed to wrap up complexities in very simple and easy to use packages that make programming more accessible so developers can acquire a wide variety of skillsets instead of needlessly specialize in only one thing.